# Qt Quick: Is it possible to have text like object with onClicked function?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I am quite new to Qt Quick.

I would love to have an object with editable text, that can also have onClicked function.

Here is a simple example, of what I would like to do:

```
TextField {
     id: myTextField
     text: qsTr("enter text here")
     font.pixelSize: 12
     onClicked: {
        myText.text = "TextField edited"
     }
}

Text {
     id: myText
     font.pixelSize: 12
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`MouseArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html):

```
TextField {
    id: myTextField
    text: qsTr("enter text here")
    font.pixelSize: 12
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:  myText.text = "TextField edited"
    }
}

Text {
    id: myText
    font.pixelSize: 12
}
```

Comment: Or [`TapHandler`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qt-labs-handlers-taphandler.html) ;)